# How to send an single email to number of users at one time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, email, carbon-copy

I want to send a single mail to number of users. I have extracted the email addresses of all those in datatable,  now I am wondering how can I pass this datatable to BCC or CC in mail.

Comment: just loop on to your table and concatente each with ; to create sing le line.

Comment: I want to send it only once i dont want to use loop.

Comment: check @HatSoft answer thats what i am saying.

Comment: @BizApps ohh sorry i got what you want to say.. Thanks \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieve it by doing something like this

```
MailMessage MyMail = new MailMessage();
 MyMail.From = "some email address";


foreach(DataRow row in dataTable1.Rows)
{
 MyMail.To += row["email"] + ";"
}
```